# Convert markdown with katex to pdf file electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, electron, markdown

I'm using electron with react to create a markdown editor. For now it renders correctly any katex.
[image]
I am using a npm library called [md-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf). And I made it work until I realized that it doesn't render any katex:
[image]

How can I use `md-to-pdf` to achieve my goal?
Here's the code for the editor:

```
import { ChangeEvent, RefObject, KeyboardEvent } from "react";
import { Box, Flex, Textarea } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import ChakraUIRenderer from "chakra-ui-markdown-renderer";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import rehypeKatex from "rehype-katex";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";
import remarkMath from "remark-math";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import remarkBreaks from "remark-breaks";
import remarkEmoji from "remark-emoji";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";

interface EditorProps {
  val: string;
  onEdit: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
  onKeyDown: (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
  txRef: RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>;
}

function Editor({ val, onEdit, onKeyDown, txRef }: EditorProps) {
  return (
    <Flex h="100%" justifyContent="center" gap="0.5rem">
      <Textarea
        ref={txRef}
        value={val}
        onChange={onEdit}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      />
      <Box
      >
        <ReactMarkdown
          components={ChakraUIRenderer()}
          skipHtml
          remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm, remarkMath, remarkBreaks, remarkEmoji]}
          rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex, rehypeRaw]}
          children={val}
        />
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  );
}
```

And here is what I tried to use to make the pdfs:

```
let sReq = await dialog.showSaveDialog(mainWindow, {
  title: "Save PDF",
  filters: [{ name: "PDF", extensions: ["pdf"] }]
});

if (sReq.canceled) return;

let pdf = await mdToPdf({ content: md }).catch(console.error);
if (pdf) {
  writeFileSync(sReq.filePath!, pdf.content);
}
```