# Markdown & Embedded diagrams Export to pdf (as expected markdown outcome)

Tags: markdown, pdf-generation, mermaid

#### What are the details of your problem?

*Introduce the problem and expand on what you put in the title. Minimum 20 characters.*

How to export Markdown with diagrams (in diagramming lanugages like [mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/), [pikchr](https://pikchr.org/home), etc) to PDF? 
I want the output pdf to look exactly same as the markdown preview. (i.e. in line breaks etc - ofc, the line wrapping etc will not be same)

Typora editor software (closed source) does this perfectly, so, is there some way to know what commands it calls so that i can replicate those manually? 
I suspect that it likely invovles rendering in chromium, then processing the output in some form via pandoc or something.

#### What did you try and what were you expecting?

*Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted. Minimum 20 characters.*

Generally, there are two issues:

1. markdown formatting (like line breaks etc) not respected
2. diagrams (like mermaid) not rendered

The other multiple different ways to export tried are:

- normal [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) (markdown to pdf via pdflatex i guess) 
  goes via pdflatex, hence follows the latex rules. therefore problem 1, and 2 above
- [zettlr](https://github.com/Zettlr/Zettlr) editor v2.3.0: both problems 1, 2 above
- VSCodium extension: jebbs.[markdown-extended](https://open-vsx.org/vscode/item?itemName=jebbs.markdown-extended) mermaid not rendered in the pdf

#### MWE

````markdown
```mermaid
---
title: Sample Mermaid
---
%%{ init: {
    'theme': 'forest', 
    'flowchart': {'curve': 'linear', 'defaultRenderer': 'elk'}
    } }%%
graph TD
A(Forest) --> B[/Another/]
A --> C[End]
  subgraph section
  B
  C
  end
```

This is a sample equation:

$$ \sqrt{a} = b ^ 3 $$


List:
* Markdown list item 1
* Item 5: Code comes from [mermaid-directives]

[mermaid-directives]: https://mermaid.js.org/config/directives.html#directive-examples

New Paragraph starts here.
````

#### Other Questions

- [Convert markdown with katex to pdf file electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267244/convert-markdown-with-katex-to-pdf-file-electron)
  This is for creating a software for doing that work